# Why won't this HTML code snippet trigger a website redirect?

Tags: html, google-sites

I am trying to embed this html snipped into my google sites website so that it redirects users to my app. For some reason, it is not working, however, I added a button that does work. Why would the button work but not the auto-redirect?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Open Custom URI Immediately</title>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // Define the custom URI you want to open
      var customUri = "striperedirect://";

      // Open the custom URI immediately
      window.location.href = customUri;
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to my Google Sites page!</h1>
  <p>This page will automatically open a custom URI immediately after it loads.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Button(working)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Open URI on Button Click</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="openURI()">Open URI</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function openURI() {
      window.open("striperedirect://"); // Replace with your desired URI
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <p>This is a test page</p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
};
</script>
</html>
```

I was able to test this code by saving it in a file, and opening that file in a browser.

I needed to add the `https://` prefix to the URL in order to make it work. (That is, in the line `window.location.href = "https://www.google.com"`.)

I mention this because it might work for you after adding the `http://` or `https://` prefix. It's one of the few noticeable differences that caught my attention.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me, I embedded it directly into my google sites page and nothing happens. I think something is up with google sites, I am going to start considering that to be the issue. Also, even if your code did work for me, I was using a custom URI so the required https wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need javascript here. A meta tag can handle this for you.

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://your-website.com/" />
```

If you want to redirect three seconds later, just replace 0 with 3.

Comment: That does not work for me, with either a custom uri or a real domain, nothing happens. I am starting to think something is off about embedding with google sites because nothing seems to be working.

Comment: This is weird. Do you have the code hosted somewhere? I can check and let you know what is wrong.